# What is the best way of reading/parsing WEB API 2 IHttpActionResult responses?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have following web api method:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var person = _personRepository.GetPersonByID(id);

        if (person == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok<Person>(person);
    }
```

And following client calling method:

```
        var data = default(IEnumerable<T>);
        var response = _client.GetAsync(relativeUri).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //string dataString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            //return response status code/reason phrase
        }
```

after ReadAsAsync call is finished, data variable indicates a collection of type T with count matching returned rows but all objects (elements) are having null valued properties or empty. 
Actual values are not being populated in properties.

Fiddler shows the JSON string. Even, ReadAsStringAsAsync() method returns JSON string.

Is there a better way to parse JSON into T type using one of ReadAsXXXX() methods?

Thanks,

-Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update that I have found the root cause of the issue that I was facing.

The code sample that I mentioned is actually the correct way of calling web api methods.

In my case, JSON string was formatted in Camel Casing at server side and at client side, default formtting was used.

this is server side code which was causing the issue:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

As soon as this was removed, it started working.

Clearly, ReadAsAsync method could not find the matching properties and therefore all values were being dropped.

Thanks,

-Jignesh